# find the first unique element in the integer list : python

Tags: python

```
def findFirstUnique(lst):
    # Write your code here
    for x in lst:
        print ('x is:{} '.format(x))
        lst.remove(x)
        print lst
        if x not in lst:
            return x

print ('final output is : {}'.format(findFirstUnique(lst)))
```

Apparently it seems to go through for certain cases like this: `[9, 2, 3, 2, 6, 6, 9]`
And for some other cases, the for loop seems to behave so weirdly: `[4, 5, 1, 2, 0, 4]`

and the output for the second case :

```
x is:4  [5, 1, 2, 0, 4] 
x is:1 >>> Why is it not picking "5" as the next value?? [5, 2, 0, 4] final output is : 1
```

I am kinda losing it now that I am not able to understand this for loop!
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do not remove elements from a list you are iterating over.

Comment: Just try this for loop, you will know why it was happened: `l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; for n in l: l.remove(n)`

Comment: @JanChristophTerasa .. am so happy to have found your answers. This is bothering me for a while .. I am kinda so confused why not to use list.remove() or list.pop() while iterating over the list in a for loop form example.. it seems to work for a few scenarios but some end up like above...can u please explain a little more.. and to justify my ask.. I have tried a lot of websites to understand this but not able to conclude

Comment: @Yang HG.. perfect.. you got me.. but am just not able to see what is going on here with the for loop? Please can u elaborate and save me some hours of time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a different approach but it will return the first unique in the list

```
def findFirstUnique(lst):
    for x in lst:
        if lst.count(x) == 1:
            return x
    return None
```

Comment: You don't need the else part just leave the return None without the else because if the for loop ends without returning result it will return None.

Comment: Thanks @AMH that is the answer to solve it but I am more asking about the for loop behavior.. in my code... but appreciate your response.. and list.count is what I ended up implementing in too..

Answer (score 1):

This should suffice, it is succinct and fast.

```
[*filter(lambda x: lst.count(x) == 1, lst)][0]
```

Data:

```
lst = [9, 2, 3, 1, 2, 6, 6, 9]
```

Comment: Succinct, yes. As regard fast, I'm not so sure. Using `lst.count(x)` is presumably faster than an explicit loop, but is still O(n), and it's implictly inside another loop of O(n). If you do a dictionary lookup from counts obtained e.g. using `collections.Counter` this will be quicker. Also computing the whole list of unique elements only to extract the first might prove to be slower than an explicit loop that you can terminate early once a match is found.

Comment: @alaniwi very true. Terminating after first match would presumably be much faster on bigger lists. Given OP's toy lists though it significantly outperforms all other answers including those using collections.Counter and terminating after first match.

Comment: Oh I'm sure you're correct about speed with small lists.

Comment: Interestingly, it still seems to perform better than collection.Counter with medium sized and large lists.

Comment: Now that is interesting. I wonder why. I presume you tried something similar to my other answer when you tested this?

Comment: Just tried it myself, and they are scaling exactly as I expected. The `collections.Counter` with explicit outer loop (per my answer) is scaling as roughly O(n) and this one is going as O(n^2), and the break-even point is at a length of only 30. This is in a test case where the first unique element is in the middle of the list.

Comment: In fact the scaling on the dictionary lookup itself was closer to O(1) even than I expected. The whole operation with n=2e5 took 48 milliseconds and with n=2e8 took 57 seconds, so the whole thing was pretty much O(n). It meant creating a big dictionary in memory though, obviously.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of speed, any solution which requires looping over the list for each element in order to check the number of counts (whether as an explicit loop or by using `lst.count()`) is going to scale as O(*n*^2) in the worst case.  If you start by making a dictionary of counts, and then use the dictionary lookup for each item to check its count, then this should be not much worse than O(*n*).  The code to obtain the counts in pure Python is not particularly difficult, but in fact `collections.Counter` in the standard library will do it for us, so we may as well use that:

```
from collections import Counter

def findFirstUnique(lst):
    counts = Counter(lst)
    for x in lst:
        if counts[x] == 1:
            return x
    else:
        return None

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    lst = [9,2,3,2,6,6,9]
    print(findFirstUnique(lst))
```

Comment: Perfect. This is the obvious best way to do this, since it is O(n).

Comment: thanks @alaniwi.. if library usage is permitted  then yes we can use Counter fro collections.

Comment: @teju_surya It is not difficult to implement `Counter` yourself if you need to, but except perhaps for learning purposes you may as well make use of functions in the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

The **for** loop actually iterates the list using the element's index (say i). At the 2nd loop, **i=1**, **lst=[5, 1, 2, 0, 4]**. So, the current element is 1, not 5. As a rule, you should not remove or insert any element while iterating.

```
def findFirstUnique(lst):
    for i, x in enumerate(lst):
        print('x is:{} '.format(x))
        print(lst[:i]+lst[i+1:])
        if x not in lst[:i]+lst[i+1:]:
            return x

print(findFirstUnique([4, 5, 1, 2, 0, 4]))
```

Comment: try this with `[4, 4, 2, 0, 1]`, it will fail. must check prev. values as well

Comment: @SơnNinh thanks for your response.. going by what you said.."The for loop actually iterates the list using the element's index (say i)"  and so when this is the list: [4, 5, 1, 2, 0, 4]                                                                                                                        first loop          i=0 and x is 4-- > expected                                                                                    second loop    i=1 and x should be =5 right ?

Comment: @teju_surya no. Because you removed the first 4, the list would be [5, 1, 2, 0, 4] at the 2nd loop.